# Bottom Sheet holding a view above a Recyclerview - view starts scrolled out of view

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

I'm having an issue with getting a Bottom Sheet to work properly

In the bottom sheet I have an item above a RecyclerView (a TextView in this case) - both of which I wish to scroll, so they're both wrapped in a NestedScrollView.

Issue is, when the screen loads, the TextView is hidden, and I must scroll the RecyclerView downward to reveal it, before being able to scroll the whole view up again to have the bottom sheet overlay the rest of the screen.

How can I make it so that the TextView is already in view?

```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="GYUHGHJG"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

```
how it starts
[image: how it starts]
how it looks after scrolling it down (how it SHOULD start)
[image: how it looks after scrolling it down and how it SHOULD start]

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a workaround and it worked!!!
It is not a valid solution but no other option..
In your example, try to use Relative layout instead of Linear layout. and provide top padding to Recycler view.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="GYUHGHJG"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: so I think I ran into the issue elsewhere after, and the solution was to set the top view (before the RecyclerView) as `focusableInTouchMode`